# Object_Detection Not working in tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, model, pycharm

I am new to tensor flow and I trained face mask model and tried it on web cam but it shows something like this.

[image]
Can anyone help me with this, I used around 100+ images and 2-3 hrs for training, where i am doing mistake can anyone help me out.

Last 2 cmd used

```
python train.py --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config --logtostderr


python export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix training/model.ckpt-0 --output_directory new_graph
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `training/model.ckpt-0` that is the first checkpoint after the model started training, you need to use the last checkpoint saved on your `training` folder.